# find links using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to get the links from script tag using bs4

here's the tag i want scrape links from

```
html = """<script type="text/javascript">var player = new Clappr.Player({
    sources: ["https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkdqatbvqbc5axyv4dpuq/v.mp4","https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkyyarbvqbc5dtluomera/v.mp4"]

    poster: "image.jpg",
    width: "100%",
height: "100%",
disableVideoTagContextMenu: true,
    parentId: "#vplayer",
    events: {
    onReady: function() {  },
    }"""
```

how can i get the links in "sources" ?

```
link1 = "https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkdqatbvqbc5axyv4dpuq/v.mp4"

link2 = "https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkyyarbvqbc5dtluomera/v.mp4"
```

links are matching so i only need 1 of them

note:
doamin  name change every time
so i can't search for example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re
html = """<script type="text/javascript">var player = new Clappr.Player({
    sources: ["https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkdqatbvqbc5axyv4dpuq/v.mp4","https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkyyarbvqbc5dtluomera/v.mp4"]

    poster: "image.jpg",
    width: "100%",
height: "100%",
disableVideoTagContextMenu: true,
    parentId: "#vplayer",
    events: {
    onReady: function() {  },
    }"""

match = re.findall(r"https.+?mp4", html)

print(match)
```

Output:

```
['https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkdqatbvqbc5axyv4dpuq/v.mp4', 'https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkyyarbvqbc5dtluomera/v.mp4']
```

Or

```py
match = re.search(r"sources: (\[.+\])", html).group(1)

print(match)
```

Output:

```
["https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkdqatbvqbc5axyv4dpuq/v.mp4","https://example.com/zx5x4vxkb52dxcne4zwsbbn6rpafhxnsodnlcjifkyyarbvqbc5dtluomera/v.mp4
```